# Python, pip: Как посмотреть зависимости конкретной версии модуля перед установкой

Tags: python, pip

Подскажите, пожалуйста, лучший способ посмотреть список зависимостей для конкретного модуля перед установкой.

Допустим у меня есть проект на **Python3.7** где есть определенный список модулей разных версий.
Мне необходимо добавить модуль **pdfplumber**. Но мне необходимо установить такую версию, что бы существующие модули не конфликтовали и не повышались в версии.

Как мне лучше всего просмотреть список зависимостей, перед установкой ?
За ранее спасибо!

Comment: Чтобы увидеть зависимости какого либо модуля перед установкой, можно попробовать использовать `pip show <имя модуля>` (например, `pip show pdfplumber`). А чтобы увидеть зависимости всех установленных модулей, можно ввести `pip freeze`

Comment: поправляю себя, `pip show` работает только в случаях когда пакет уже установлен.

Comment: Вот в этом и вопрос. Эта команда не подходит. Есть ли способ проверить перед установкой ?

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать `pip download` для скачивания пакета напрямую и их зависимостей вместе без установки

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Вариант 1 - смотрим json через [pypi.org](https://pypi.org)**

Делаем запрос по имени библиотеки и версии, в данном случае

```
https://pypi.org/pypi/pdfplumber/0.9.0/json
```

в Json находим параметр `"requires_dist"`:

```
"requires_dist": [
 "pdfminer.six (==20221105)",
 "Pillow (>=9.1)",
 "Wand (>=0.6.10)"
]
```

---

**Вариант 2 - для Windows**

Хорошим методом будет являться скачивание модуля в виде архива и просмотр файла `requirements.txt`. Для этого можно воспользоваться командой в `powershell`:

```
pip download pdfplumber --no-deps --no-binary=:all:
```

После этого откройте скачанный архив и найдите там файл `requirements.txt`
В моем случае внутри он выглядит так:

```
pdfminer.six==20221105
Pillow>=9.1
Wand>=0.6.10
```

**UPD.0**
Если убрать из команды `--no-deps`, то возможно скачивание сразу и зависимых библиотек, но это приведет к их установке.

**UPD.1**
Для скачивания архива для последующего нахождения зависимостей конкретной версии библиотеки, можно действовать так:

```
pip download pdfplumber==<версия> --no-deps --no-binary=:all:
```

Где `<версия>` - это версия вашей библиотеки, соответственно.

**UPD.2**
Для нахождения зависимостей зависимостей, откройте первый `requirements.txt` и повторите операцию по скачиванию файла архива библиотеки для каждой зависимости, затем откройте их собственные `requirements.txt` если таковые имеются.

Comment: По хорошему бы создать автоматизацию этого процесса, но это второй вопрос...